# Reasons to Install Visual Studio on a Production Web Server

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2012

Is there a legitimate reason for someone to have Visual Studio installed on a Web Server whose sole purpose is to serve incoming requests? Seriously, are there any particular reasons someone might do this?

Comment: No, there is no legitimate reason that I know of.

Answer (score 3):

One possible use is to attach to the web server and debug some kind of error or memory leak that has proven impossible to find on a development machine.  Depending on the setup, remote debugging might be a better option.  For us, as an ISV, it is not, because we often connect to customer systems via LiveMeeting and other very unproductive means to diagnose problems in production.  The few times I have had to debug a running process on a customer system, I downloaded and used [WinDbg](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463009.aspx).

A better option for debugging production systems is to use tracing, logging, and memory dumps.  Someone could use Visual Studio to attach to the w3wp.exe process and [save a memory dump file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/d5zhxt22.aspx#BKMK_How_to_create_a_dump_file).  However, if all they need is a memory dump, there are other more efficient means of gathering one: [Task Manager](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/931673), [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx), etc.

Someone also might be using it a very expensive editor for viewing XML, config, or html files, but that is not a legitimate use.

I sincerely hope nobody is actually writing code on this machine.  You might do a quick search for project files in user folders, if you have accesss.

So are there reasons someone might install Visual Studio on a production web server?  Yes, it could be useful.  But that doesn't mean it's a *good* idea.

Comment: It's worth noting that you _can_ configure remote debugging and skip having it installed locally but it can be a pain to do, especially across trust boundaries - eg debugging production from the dev environment.

Comment: -1: I disagree that this is a legitimate scenario. Use remote debugging if you have to.

Comment: @JohnSaunders I often connect to customer systems (databases, web servers, and terminal servers) via LiveMeeting, VNC, etc.  Remote debugging is not an option for us most of the time.  We rely heavily on logging and memory dumps when  necessary.  However, I'll note the remote debugging option in my answer.

Comment: Do you connect to these systems for the purpose of running Visual Studio?

Comment: Usually not.  The few times I have had to debug a process, I relied on WinDbg.  The OP asked, "Are there reasons someone might do this?"  Yes, it could be useful, but the alternatives are more attractive.

Comment: That's the reason I say installing VS is not a good use case. Installing Windbg _is_ a good use case.

Answer (score 0):

Our test/dev server does have VS (2017) installed.
We are in the process of migrating to a new server with Windows 2019/VS2019. We also use new reporting components (Crystal SP 31, and a newer version of MS Reporting Services Project and MS Analysis Services Project components).
For the MS components, I installed them from within VS 2019 in the new prod (staging) server, that is the reason I had to install VS in a PROD server.
I plan now to uninstall VS from the PROD server (just because as a good practice, dev components like VS should not be running on a PROD server). Do you see any negative side effects to this and was there another way to get those MS components installed?

Answer (score -2):

I come at this with a different point of view.  Yes as others stated you can use other tools to debug a production support issue on the web server or remotely but there are legitimate reasons to install Visual Studio on a production web server.  I've also been put in situations due to the businesses I've worked for in which the developers are put in a bad position in which it's necessary to do so.  My current employer for instance has never setup a QA web server.  So I'm stuck with local development and deploying test sites in production to test.  3 years have gone by and I still haven't had a resource assigned to provision the new web server.     Remote access debugging based on my experience has not been the best method to troubleshoot production specific issues due to the companies policies and is in certain circumstances problematic and not available option for everyone.  Some examples of issues are firewall issues, IP/domain network issues, and security issues as all public web servers are on the DMZ.   My experience with remote debugging has been nil as the network teams at my employers did not allow me to open ports and make it possible because the server was on the DMZ.  Also depending on your version of Visual Studio remote debugging was buggy and never worked (not tried it yet with new versions as I cannot do it at work).  As long as the program is installed for use by authorized personnel I do not see a down side for having it available for emergency production support issues only.    I personally had countless experiences in which the errors were specific to the production web server that could not be reproduced locally or on a QA or development server and the quickest and easiest solution was to debug the issue on the production web server.  The fix was made in Dev and QA tested and then applied to production work around tools don't always report the specific issue.  The best solution at the time was to debug it directly in production.   I'm sure there will be those that will say its a security risk but if the applications are secured I do not see a down side for having the best debug tool at your disposal in case of emergencies.  There are also implications of using VS in production like IIS resets which is why it should be limited to debug the issue only. I want to add that I only recommend this for emergencies only.  This also does not work for every business as some do not allow developers access to the web servers.  In my instances I've always been responsible for the web server and the applications themselves.  The use of this option should be limited in scope to only emergencies in which the issue could not be resolved using other methods and programming fixes for the issue should never be done directly in production.  In the end sometimes it may be necessary and maybe you may need to install it after hours and then remove it after the issue has been resolved.  Under normal circumstances you wouldnt install anything unnecessary in production but sometimes I feel it may be necessary.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/275037/is-it-safe-and-acceptable-to-install-vs-net-on-your-production-server/33394813#33394813

Comment: Posting the exact same answer to different questions seems like a good way to attract down votes ;)